# Merged standard Dict and TypedDict to form a TypedDict in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeddict

I'm trying to use code like this to create a TypedDict which is a superset of another TypedDict:

```py
from typing import TypedDict


class Base(TypedDict):
    a: str


class Extend(Base):
    b: str


base_instance: Base = {"a": "string!"}

extend_instance: Extend = {**base_instance, "b": "another string"}
```

But this emits a diagnostic warning about `extend_instance`: "Expression of type "dict[str, object | str]" cannot be assigned to declared type "Extend""

It's not clear to me why the values in `extend_instance` are assumed to be `object | str`, rather than just `str`.

Is there something I can do to annotate this better?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could add a `# noinspection PyTypeChecker` before the last line to suppress the warning

Comment: @rv.kvetch thanks but I'm hoping there's a way besides suppression :fingers_crossed:

Comment: The code above works for me in pyhton 3.11 and Pylance.